# azure pipeline flutter firebase project ios build error

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, azure-pipelines

use azure pipeline to build a flutter firebase project ,flutter build and pod install all succeed,but xcode can't find module firebase-core .

my source build succeed on mac,but failed on azure pipeline.
my pipeline:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'
  
variables:
      # FYI: Did you know, all Azure Pipeline variables are added to the build system environment?
      # The following variables will prevent Xcode from code-signing during build.
      # This is necessary, because we do not want to CI builds to be sensitive to code-signing settings configured by 
      # developers during development.
      # The 'exportOptions' will ultimately handle the code signing with the correct cert/prov profile.
      FLUTTER_XCODE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: ""
      FLUTTER_XCODE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED: NO 
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'certificate.p12'
    certPwd: 'password'
    keychain: 'temp'
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'myapp.mobileprovision'  
- task: FlutterInstall@0
  inputs:
    mode: 'auto'
    channel: 'stable'
    version: 'custom'
    customVersion: '3.10.5'
- task: FlutterBuild@0
  inputs:
    target: 'ipa'
    projectDirectory: '.'
    exportOptionsPlist: 'ios/ExportOptions.plist'   
    extraArgs: '--release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'cd ios && pod install'
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: ''
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode Archive iOS'
  inputs:
    actions: 'archive'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/Runner.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'Runner'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    configuration: 'Release'
    exportOptionsPlist: 'ios/ExportOptions.plist'
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWYY9.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuH85.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WscWv.png)

flutter build and pod install all succeed,but xcode can't find module firebase-core ,any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the following ways to fix the issue:

1. As mentioned [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#installation), run the command line below to install the **`firebase_core`** plugin.

   ```bash
   flutter pub add firebase_core
   ```
2. Go the **`ios`** folder, and then do below things.

   - Run command line '**`pod repo update`**'.
   - Run command line '**`pod deintegrate`**'.
   - Remove the **`Podfile.lock`** file. You can try to run command line '**`flutter clean`**' to do this.
   - Run command line '**`pod install`**'.

Comment: 1,my pubspec.yaml already has firebase_core: ^2.20.0 and flutter build install it successfully.

Comment: 2.I have deleted podfile.lock and run pod install ,firebase_core has been added and installed, as the second image, but it not work

Comment: @nagi, Did you try the '**`pod install`**' and '**`xcode build`**' for the same flutter firebase project on your local macOS machine (or VM)? Does the same issue exist? If the issue does not exist locally, try to set up a [self-hosted macOS agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/osx-agent?view=azure-devops) on your local macOS machine to run the pipeline job.

Comment: as I say on line3, my source build succeed on mac , and has been published to apple store,but on azure pipeline it failed with /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: module 'firebase_core' not found

Comment: @nagi, Try a self-hosted macOS agent on your local macOS machine to run the pipeline job to see if it can work? And what is the version of your local macOS?

Comment: my mac system version is 13.4 , I don't know how to use self-hosted macOS agent to complete the pipelines as azure  , is that necessary? I just learn to use mac and xcode and the task seems not easy...

Comment: @nagi, Try the MS hosted **`macOS-13`** agent. And to set up a self-hosted macOS agent, see the link I had shared in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank YOU very much! I will study and try it!

Comment: Unfortunately,I set up a self-hosted macOS agent and it give me a same result as above...